# How to add Polygon Collider 2D to Line Renderer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to add a Polygon collider using C# as is shown in [this link](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/add-collider-to-line-renderer-unity).

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [PolygonCollider2D.SetPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.SetPath.html), where you could set points, which define the outline of the polygon.